# spark-submit cannot find python script

Tags: apache-spark

I am getting the following error

```
16/06/29 15:04:36 ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Added file file:/path/to/app/model_app.py does not exist.
```

When I run the command

```
local:~ noob$ spark-submit --master local[*] --jars /path/to/jar/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar /path/to/app/model_app.py
```

My env vars are as follows

```
export SPARK_HOME=/Users/noob/spark-1.5.0-bin-hadoop2.6
export PATH=$PATH:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/jars
export PYTHONPATH=$SPARK_HOME/python/:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip:$PYTHONPATH
```

If I move the python script to `$SPARK_HOME/python` and run spark-submit from that folder then everything runs fine.

If I add `/path/to/app` to `$PYTHONPATH` or `$PATH` - I still get the file not found error.

There obviously is a better way to run a spark app than by adding app.py script to `$SPARK_HOME/python` folder and then running it from inside the folder.

What am I missing here? Also what is a good way to run a spark job on schedule (like a cron job)?